# Install ffmpeg in Centos 7

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, centos7

I am new to Centos.
When I tried to install ffmpeg in Centos, followed this [link](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-centos/).

```
Error: Package: ffmpeg-2.8.15-2.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.8.15-2.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libschroedinger-1.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.8.15-2.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libopenal.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.8.15-2.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.8.15-2.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libass.so.5()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

When I tried to install `libSDL-1.2.so.0`, I have another dependencies errors.
What is usual practice of installation in Centos?

Comment: So where should I ask such question?

Answer (score 0):

I go to Centos repository and download rpm binary package.
Then use the command as follow.
sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall xxxxxxxxxxx.rpm

If there are dependency packages to install, I tried to install those dependencies first.

Answer (score 0):

We need to install epel repository first for Centos 7.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-redhat-7-x/

Then install from epel repository using `yum install command`.